# Getting result from select command [SQL]

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is my table:

```
INSERT INTO Emp (EmpNo, EName, Job, Mgr, HireDate, Sal, Comm, DeptNo) 
VALUES (7369, 'SMITH', 'CLERK', 7902, '1980-12-17', 800, NULL, 20), 
       (7499, 'ALLEN', 'SALESMAN', 7698, '1981-02-20', 1600, 300, 30), 
       (7521, 'WARD', 'SALESMAN', 7698, '1981-02-22', 1250, 500, 30), 
       (7566, 'JONES', 'MANAGER', 7839, '1981-04-02', 2975, NULL, 20), 
       (7654, 'MARTIN', 'SALESMAN', 7698, '1981-09-28', 1250, 1400, 30), 
       (7698, 'BLAKE', 'MANAGER', 7839, '1981-05-01', 2850, NULL, 30), 
       (7782, 'CLARK', 'MANAGER', 7839, '1981-06-09', 2450, NULL, 10), 
       (7788, 'SCOTT', 'ANALYST', 7566, '1987-04-19', 3000, NULL, 20), 
       (7839, 'KING', 'PRESIDENT', NULL, '1981-11-17', 5000, NULL, 10), 
       (7844, 'TURNER', 'SALESMAN', 7698, '1981-09-08', 1500, 0, 30), 
       (7876, 'ADAMS', 'CLERK', 7788, '1987-05-23', 1100, NULL, 20), 
       (7900, 'JAMES', 'CLERK', 7698, '1981-12-03', 950,NULL, 30),
       (7902, 'FORD', 'ANALYST', 7566, '1981-12-03', 3000, NULL, 20),
       (7934, 'MILLER', 'CLERK', 7782, '1982-01-23', 1300, NULL, 10);
```

Now I want to get every worker who their job isn't PRESIDENT or MANAGER.

This is my command:

```
SELECT * 
FROM [dbo].EMP 
WHERE NOT Job = 'MANAGER' OR Job = 'PRESIDENT';
```

The result is almost correct, but I get one PRESIDENT who shouldn't be there.

This one:

```
7839    KING    PRESIDENT   NULL    1981-11-17  5000.00 NULL    10
```

Comment: What rdbms you are using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to wrap it with brackets:

```
SELECT * FROM [dbo].EMP WHERE NOT (Job='MANAGER' OR Job='PRESIDENT');
```

Or use `NOT IN`:

```
SELECT * FROM [dbo].EMP WHERE Job NOT IN ('MANAGER', 'PRESIDENT');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `NOT IN`

```
SELECT * FROM [dbo].EMP WHERE Job NOT in  ('MANAGER' ,'PRESIDENT')
```